# Word order of "Blessed are the meek"

Tags: word-order

I am wondering why the word order is inverted in these sentences:

> Blessed are the meek.
>
> Blessed are the poor.

It seems to me that the inversion is relevant to the adjective **blessed**. Can someone shed some light on it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reverse the order of any sentence like this and have it remain grammatical. *Long is the day.* *Rumbling is my stomach.* It's not common to do so, but it's acceptable. This is a particular phrase that, for some reason (probably because of repetition from religious texts), ended up being more common than its reverse. *The meek are blessed* is also grammatical, just less common.

<sub>(Transcribed from comment)</sub>

Comment: Is there any nuances between "Blessed are the meek" and "the meek are blessed."?

Comment: The difference is mostly in register; the former is more “poetic” or “literary”.